# Why this.props returns old data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I use: **react *v16.2.0***, **redux *v3.7.2***, **react-redux *v5.0.6*** in my project. And I noticed mysterious behaviour in certain case of code.

For example i want register method ***handleScroll*** for ***MyComponent***. Lets say, in this method i need to access ***state.MyComponent.ui.myobject***. So to access it i declare ***mapStateToProps*** that will register its value to ***this.props.myobject***. Example code:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  myobject: state.MyComponent.ui.myobject
  // ...
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  // ...
})

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }
  handleScroll () {
    let myobject = this.props.myobject;
    // do calculations
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementById('body').addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  };
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.getElementById('body').removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  };
  render(){
    return (
      <div>{/*content*/}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent);
```

In this case everything works well and without bugs. But, when i try to declare function ***handleScroll*** outside the component class, in some point of time ***this.props.myobject*** starts to return old data. Example code:

```
let handleScroll = function () {
  let myobject = this.props.myobject;
  // do calculations
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  myobject: state.MyComponent.ui.myobject
  // ...
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  // ...
})

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    handleScroll = handleScroll.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementById('body').addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  };
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.getElementById('body').removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  };
  render(){
    return (
      <div>{/*content*/}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent);
```

I dont have any idea why its so. Anyone know what can be happened in this case? Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you run:

```
handleScroll = handleScroll.bind(this)
```

... you overwrite the handleScroll reference which is defined at the module level (essentially global scope but only visible to the module).  The first code sample makes more sense.  Without seeing all the code it's difficult to know exactly what's going on, but if you create more than one instance of MyComponent then I can see how you might have observed something like what you're describing.

Also, you didn't ask but I don't get what you're doing here - state should never contain components:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    myobject: state.MyComponent.ui.myobject
    // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the second example you should use `this.handleScroll` instead of just `handleScroll`. That way `this` will always point to the right contex of the component.